# Visual Studio dashed lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I accidentally pressed something and now there are dashed lines before each line of code. How to remove it?

[image]

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. This is asking about dashed lines, not dots. Just because both questions have the same answer does not mean it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to turn on/off, do the following:

```
Edit > Advanced > View white space
```

or using keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: Isn't it `CTRL + R, CTRL + W`?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, Some keyboard schemes differ. Even the "default" schemes on 2 boxes at my work are different.

Comment: @gunr2171: When you goto `Edit > Advanced > View white space` in vs it shows as `CTRL + R, CTRL + W`. Thats why I was wondering !

Comment: Both `CTRL + E, S` and `CTRL + R, CTRL + W` work for me.

Comment: interesting, `CTRL + R, CTRL + W` doesn't work for me. I'm using visual studio 2012 also.

Comment: @今草顿웃: Oh! mine is `2010` :)

Answer (score 1):

That's just showing you whitespace by putting dots and arrows where spaces and tabs are.

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to turn it on/off.